# Problems changing SQL query with ajax on button click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Updated for @RoyalBG

Buttons:

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-default myButton" type="button" value="1">Auto</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-default myButton" type="button" value="2">Easy</button>
```

Ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".myButton",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'get',
            url: "auto.php",
            data: {
                auto_value : value
            }
            success: function (response) {
                $("#auto_content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

auto.php:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$auto_value = '1';
if (isset($_GET['auto_value'])) {
    if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 1) {
        $auto_value = 't.style = 0 and t.type = 0';
    } else if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 2) {
        $auto_value = 't.style = 1 and t.type = 0';
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT m.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(t.Time,3)) AS Time, p.User FROM times t INNER JOIN maps m ON t.MapID = m.MapID INNER JOIN players p ON p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID INNER JOIN (SELECT t.MapId, MIN(t.time) as time FROM times t WHERE ".$auto_value." GROUP BY t.MapId ) tmin ON tmin.MapId = t.MapId and tmin.time = t.time";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<table class='table table-striped table-fixedheader sortable'><thead><tr><th data-defaultsort='asc'>Map</th><th>Time</th><th>Player</th></tr></thead><tbody style='height:300px' class='searchable'>";
// output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr><td>".$row["MapName"]."</td><td>".$row["Time"]."</td><td>".$row["User"]."</td></tr>";
 }
      echo "</tbody></table>";
 } else {
      echo "0 results";
 }
 $conn->close();
```

?>

And the include:

```
 <div id="auto_content">
 <?php include 'auto.php'; ?>
 </div>
```

Upon clicking the buttons the table doesn't change. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong or not.
Also, could it be that the script is loaded after the include?

Comment: when the button is clicked, the code should work ok, the main problem is your auto.php is included in index.php where you might not have passed a get param `auto_value`. Why is your `auto.php` automatically included in `index.php`

Comment: Because I wan't the table to display on the index (same page as buttons) @RoyalBg

Comment: Set a default value to `auto_value` then, when a get param does not exists

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Even after clicking the button auto the table doesn't update with results. @RoyalBg

Comment: your `success` promise has no body, nothing will change to the presentation layer. Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is HIGHLY VULNERABLE to an SQL injection.

You are passing a BUTTON VALUE directly to an SQL statement, with the CLEAR IDEA OF ALTERING the SQL statement like adding something to the WHERE clause.

What would happen if I change the value of the button to some `1 OR 1 UNION ...` or any other SQL code pass that will break your default behavior.

I highly recommend you to change your approach. For example using enumerations. Auto button will send `auto_value=1` then in your code you need to test the `auto_value` and execute different parents of SQL appending.

E.g.:

```
$auto_value = '1';
if (isset($_GET['auto_value'])) {
    if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 1) {
        $auto_value = 't.style = 0 and t.type = 0';
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT m.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(t.Time,3)) AS Time, p.User FROM times t INNER JOIN maps m ON t.MapID = m.MapID INNER JOIN players p ON p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID INNER JOIN (SELECT t.MapId, MIN(t.time) as time FROM times t WHERE ".$auto_value." GROUP BY t.MapId ) tmin ON tmin.MapId = t.MapId and tmin.time = t.time";
```

This way you will also set a default behaviour if `auto_value` is not send via request. The default behaviour is `WHERE 1` which is like not having any where clause, so it will list everything.

Keep in mind you do not have anything in your `success` callback, so in the presentation layer NOTHING will happen upon click. The `auto.php` will be called, the SQL executed and the HTML rendered on the server side, but its response will never be caught and presented to the end user.

You might have included `auto.php` upon page load, but that's how HTTP protocol works - once delivered, it's static. Your async requests will not alter the `auto.php` content included. You need to work with the DOM in order to change the page view. In your `success` promise you might want to fill an HTML element with the content displayed by `auto.php` for example.

Let me explain with a brief example.

You are on the page `x.php`.

It contains the following code:

index.php:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="auto_content">
    <?php include 'auto.php'; ?>
</div>
<button id="btn1" class="myButton" type="button" value="1">Button one</button>
<button id="btn2" class="myButton" type="button" value="2">Button two</button>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click",".myButton",function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'get',
                url: "auto.php",
                data: {
                    auto_value : value
                },
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

auto.php:

```
<?php
$text = "default text";
if (isset($_GET)) {
    if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 1) {
        $text = "button 1 clicked";
    } else if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 2) {
        $text = "second button clicked";
    }
}
?>

<h1><?= $text; ?></h1>
```

This page prints `default text` in `<h1>` tags uppon load.

When you click either `Button one` or `Button two` a request to `auto.php` will be send and a response with either `<h1>button 2 clicked</h1>` or `<h1>second button clicked</h1>` will be recieved. It will be send via HTTP and nothing will be altered. The actual `auto.php` included in `index.php` WILL NOT change.

If you want to change the presentation without reloading the page, you need to use javascript to control the UI. You might spot that I have included `auto.php` in a div with id `auto_content`. The thing you need to do is, to load the respones from `auto.php` in that div, so its content to change with either for the first button clicked or the second.

In your success callback you will recieve the whole response as plain text in the variable `response`.

In this simple example you need only to load it as HTML into the div `auto_content`.

So you need this:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#auto_content").html(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! How can I add multiple button presses to this? Can I just create another button with the same `id=btn1` and a `value=2` and an else statement after `if ($_GET['auto_value'] == 1) {
        $auto_value = 't.style = 0 and t.type = 0';` 
Saying if auto_value = 2 it does `t.style = 1 and t.type = 0`?

Comment: You can, but not with `id`. It's not permitted to have more than one element with the same `id` attribute. Use `class` instead. So your second button with the same `class` will have for example `value=2` then you can use `else/elseif` to catch that value :)

Comment: How do I look for this class in the ajax script? Or am I mistaken, do I need to do something else?

Comment: The class is prefixed with a dot (`.`) instead of how ID is with hash (`#`).

Comment: Oh, thankyou :) So ajax will support multiple of the same classes, but not multiple of the same id's? I also tried adding an else if statement but am getting a syntax error :|

Comment: There is no reason to get syntax error in adding and else if unless you really made a syntax error? Maybe you need to check in the php manual how to use else if statement? :) And yes, about the first question, but that's not the ajax, it's the DOM. If you use some trendy IDE for web development like `WebStorm/PHPStorm` and you write two divs with the same ID's it will scream :)

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error, but upon clicking my second button the table isn't changing? Do I have to do some sort of update after running it?

Comment: Is it changing upon clicking the first button? Because as my last 2 paragraphs are saying - you are not doing anything in order to change the presentation? Have you fixed that?

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in there as the php is already being included and I see the table. I'm not experienced at all in ajax, and average at web.

Comment: The idea behind that is you are making a REQUEST and you are recieving a RESPONSE depending on what request have you made. The RESPONSE (the html and all the other stuff from auto.php) has nothing to do with the already included `auto.php` it's just a response with a bunch of text send via the HTTP. You need to catch that response in your success callback (the variable `response` in it, contains it) and do something like load it into div, etc.

Comment: I have changed the success too: `success: function($("#phpinc").load("index.php #phpinc");)` and have created a div around the php include, still, nothing changes. 
Also as a test in the `auto.php` I changed `$auto_value = '1';` to 2, which is in the elseif statement and it still seems to be defaulting to 1. I did this to try see if there was a problem with the other scripts.

If it helps, I can edit my question to show what the code currently is.

Comment: @CBlank see my edit of the answer, I added some examples (they are tested)

Comment: So, I've done exactly what you have done in your (great) example, but obviously with my code, and the table still isn't updating/changing. Not sure if this is a problem on my part or what. Will the table not update like that if it is done using `echo`? I'm not totally sure. I have updated the question to show the current code. Thanks for the great example though!

Comment: I used your code, just changed the query to fit one of my dummy tables and everything works fine, really cannot find the problem this way. Does the div refill? Could you track the requests in the NET tab of the developer tools (f12)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by div refilling but nothing changes in it visually. When using the NET tab and upon clicking the buttons nothing shows up.

Comment: Any errors in the console tab? Because it means that the javascript does not find your buttons in order to execute the ajax.

Comment: Nope, nothing at all shows up... I don't get it.. Could something else in the page be messing with it?

Comment: totally possible, try to leave only the relevant parts, as in my example ... if it works, then try to add back the things you removed until you reach the "nothing happens" moment, they you will know where the problem is

Comment: I've removed everything, and only kept the necessary like jquery. Pretty much looks the same as your example, except it's still not working... The only difference is that in the network tab of developer tools I'm getting stuff. `auto.php?auto_value=1` after clicking the buttons, upon clicking that response, I see the response with the table, but it's not showing/updating on the page. Is this a problem with the script? EDIT: I'm dumb, I forgot too add the success callback, works great now! Thanks for all your help. Now to find what's causing it to not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['auto_value'])) {

   //Your code goes here

}else {

 echo "Auto Value not received!";

}
```